# odoo: who to set a user can read all project?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

They are multi company, and a user is part of some company.
How to set a rule, that give to all users access that they can see all projects, even if they are not part of the company?

I tried this: `[(1,'=',1)]`

It isnt working. I have to change the company from the top

Answer (score 0):

- The user should have access to Project Manager and
- make "Project: multi-company" record rule inactive.

Comment: Create new access rule for global user or group to which you want to provide an access right.